# Is it possible for Visio to automatically layout a UML diagram?

Tags: uml, diagramming

Is there a way to just lay everything out in the "best" possible manner, using the entire drawing area available? Or do I have to position the various elements myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the "Lay Out Shapes" dialog in Visio 2003. Go to the Shape menu and click on the "Lay Out Shapes" menu item. It can have some interesting results, but it might help if you play around with it.

Answer (score -2):

yes it is possible. 
Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140255(office.10).aspx)

You can import your database into visio and it will create diagrams from it..

Comment: I'm not reverse engineering code and I don't have a database. I didn't see anything on that link that would help me.